# Submit input file to server side in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, file, file-upload

I want to upload a select on the client side and the pass it to the server side to be uploaded.

On the server side, I have a rest service which handles multi-part POSTs at the URL "/uploadFile".

At the server side I use this element :

```
  <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="fom" action="/uploadFile">
             File to upload:
            <input type="file" id="file"><br />
            <input type="button" id="upload"> Press here to upload the file!
            </form>
```

And it works well.

Now, I want to be able to select the file from the client side, and the pass it to the server side to be uploaded.

So ton the client side, I have this element on the page:

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="fom">
         File to upload:
        <input type="file" id="file"><br />
        <input type="button" id="upload"> Press here to upload the file!
        </form>
```

Which is basically the same, just without the 'action' attribute.

So, the user can select a file via "File open..." dialog in the browser.

From here, I don't know how to link the submitted file in the client side to the service to the server side. How can I call the service, knowing that the server and the client sides are not deployed on the same port.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using AJAX to be able to do that. 
Getting Ajax to send the file data was a bit tricky as it is not the present as a parameter in the URL server.

[This](http://digipiph.com/blog/submitting-multipartform-data-using-jquery-and-ajax) helped me a lot.

Here is what I used :

On the page :

```
        <form id="fileForm" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        File to upload:
        <input type="file" name="file" id="file"><br />
        <input type="submit" value="Upload"> Press here to upload the file!
        </form>
        <div id="response"></div>
```

On JS part :

```
  $("#file").click(function(){
    document.getElementById('fileForm').setAttribute("action", URL );
  }


  $("#fileForm").submit(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var formData = new FormData($("#fileForm")[0]);
    $.ajax({ 
        data:  formData, // get the form data
        type: $("#fileForm").attr('method'),
        url: $("#fileForm").attr('action'),
        async: false,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        complete: function(response) { 
            document.getElementById("response").innerHTML = response.responseText; // update the DIV
        }
        });
    return false;
  }
```